# SQL Presto: correlated subquery is not supported

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, join, amazon-athena, presto

Consider table `x`

```
id,val
1,100
3,300
```

And table `y`

```
id
1
2
3
```

For each row of `y` I want the `val` from `x` where the `id` from y is equal or is the closest before the `id` from `x` like that:

```
id,val
1,100
2,100
3,300
```

I tried to find the closest id with correlated subquery:

```sql
WITH 
x AS (SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1, 100),(3, 300)) AS t(id, val)),
y AS (SELECT * FROM (VALUES 1,2,3) AS t(id))
SELECT *, (
    SELECT x.id
    FROM x
    WHERE x.id <= y.id
    ORDER BY x.id DESC
    LIMIT 1
) as closest_id
FROM y
```

But I get

```
SYNTAX_ERROR: line 5:5: Given correlated subquery is not supported
```

I also tried with a left join:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM y
LEFT JOIN x ON x.id <= (
    SELECT MAX(xbis.id) FROM x AS xbis WHERE xbis.id <= y.id
)
```

But I get the error

```
SYNTAX_ERROR: line 7:5: Correlated subquery in given context is not supported
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try joining based on less then condition and then group the results and find needed data from the grouping:

```sql
WITH 
x AS (SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1, 100),(3, 300),(4, 400)) AS t(id, val)),
y AS (SELECT * FROM (VALUES 1,2,3,4) AS t(id))

SELECT y.id as yId,
    max(x.id) as xId,
    max_by(x.val, x.id) as val
FROM y
JOIN x on x.id <= y.id
GROUP BY y.id
ORDER BY y.id
```

Output:

| yId | xId | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 1 | 100 |
| 3 | 3 | 300 |
| 4 | 4 | 400 |

Answer (score -1):

You use like this i think its work...

```
SELECT *, (
    SELECT top 1  x.val
    FROM x
    WHERE x.id <= y.id
    ORDER BY x.id DESC
    
) as closest_id
FROM y
```

Comment: `TOP` does not exists in presto, we use `LIMIT` instead, this does not work

Comment: above solution working on Sql server.

Comment: this is presto tagged